# Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N 6230 no valid IP address only at school

Tags: windows-8, wireless-adapter, intel-centrino

I have been having this issue for a while. I have never had an issue with wifi till I've tried to connect to my school's wifi. I have windows 8 and the above wireless adapter. I have re-installed the driver twice, once completely removing the drive and all files using the device manager then installing, and finally restarting. No one else I know has this issue and my phone connects to it fine. Windows 8 will constantly say that I don't have a valid IP configuration, and sometimes that the default gateway is not accessible. Half the time troubleshooting and it resetting the wireless adapter will get it to start working again. Sometimes it won't even work after a restart. It seems pretty random and the only sure way I know of to reproduce the problem is to do a regular shutdown then boot back up. Does anybody have any ideas?

Couple of files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qs6ofc8a64aqje2/j6YzplpAQF

First is a screenshot of weird ping action when I try pinging the router. Second is a couple of event logs I found that may be related. Last is a screenshot of ipconfig which was asked for below

Comment: When it says you have an invalid IP configuration, what's the output of `ipconfig` for that adapter?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use a different network, or is it only for this one network? If it's just the one, chances are you have an incompatibility in the implementation of your adapter vs. the implementation of the school's AP. Incompatibility problems with WiFi are **extremely** common (just search SuperUser questions tagged wireless or wifi), because the specs are so loosely-worded that 10 manufacturers can do things 10 different, incompatible ways. That's why I suggest everyone either use cellular data (3G, 4G) or ethernet.

Comment: @allquixotic No, it is only on this particular wifi, which is a bunch of network routers working as one really. College wifi. I've had an issue kinda like this on a previous android phone. And that' ridiculous about the specs being that loosely worded. I've updated the question with a link to a couple files and I'll get the ipconfig tomorrow

Comment: Have you been able to connect before? Try changing your MAC adress, the school may have blocked your MAC Adress. I've seen this work before.

Comment: @MDTGuy I've never connected to this network before. If they blocked my MAC address wouldn't I not be able to get internet at all? I can usually connect to it if I restart. I'm seeing a lot about the DHCP server not being able to give me an IP address or something. And aren't MAC addresses unique so that there's no way they could have blocked my MAC address intending block out someone else in the past correct?